# How to limit quota(traffic) usage per user in openvpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to limit quota used by my openvpn server.

Example :

User 1 : limit to 5gb per month

User 2 : limit to 15gb per month

Comment: Not sure, but maybe Openvpn RADIUS Accounting can give you hints unless you get better answers.

Comment: @NikiZe can we write script for handle new requests throw vpn and add size of bytes sended or received to a file with user name and check if is it bigger than 5gb or not